# Spring security return 403 during login running in embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Previous this project without embedded Tomcat, package as war running Tomcat, spring security login was fine.
I have no idea where to debug now, no Exception raise... I suspect is login spring security filter order mess up the login process, maybe the CSRF token pass in without check first and result 403...

Stuck here few days still no luck... Appreciate any suggestion! Thanks

Here is my POM:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- 2nd level cache -->
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Additional add-on -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lucee/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lucee</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Enable JSP in Tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <!--scope>provided</scope-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!--scope>provided</scope-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Enable Spring security taglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Enable String AOP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Below for quartz scheduler support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dexcoder</groupId>
      <artifactId>dexcoder-dal-spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.eraseCredentials(false);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(
        UserDetail.ROLETITLE_ADMIN, UserDetail.ROLETITLE_SUPERADMIN).antMatchers("/superadmin/**").hasAnyAuthority(
        UserDetail.ROLETITLE_SUPERADMIN).antMatchers("/mobile/**").authenticated().antMatchers(
        "/history/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()

        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter(
        "password").and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")

        .and().sessionManagement().sessionFixation().none();
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
// this no execute when login using POST method after embedded Tomcat
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

    //For versioning of static resources
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/include/**");
    super.configure(web);
}
}
```

Comment: try disabling `csrf`, `http.csrf().disable();`

Comment: Did you solve this?  How?